# How to load images from the phone taken in last hour?

Tags: android, android-image, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I want to load and display all images that are taken by my phone in last hour. I am using Content Resolver query with some parameters to get images list. I can use this to display just last 10 images:

```
String sortOrder = String.format("%s limit 50 ", MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
```

And that is working with code from below, but I want to modify my cursor query to just display images taken in last hour.

Here is the code:

```
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC LIMIT 10";

    //Current time in millis and hour ago
    int now = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    long hourAgo = now - 60*60000;


    String[] columns = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,  // get the image
    };

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();


    // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
    cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            null,
            orderBy);
    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
```

**How I can only get list of images taken in last hour?**

I tried to write this also, but it does not work:

```
    final String[] selectionArgs = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + "<"+ Long.toString(hourAgo) };
    cursor = contentResolver.query( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            cols, // Which columns to return
            null,       // Return all rows
            selectionArgs ,
            orderBy);
```

Comment: You can get data and time of image by `ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN`, then you can implement logic. :)

Comment: Yeah, but then I would need to limit to display only small number of images, because there is no need to load all of them, when I just looking for images taken in last hour. But what if I take a 100 images in last hour?

Comment: `ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN` Give The date & time that the image was taken in units of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. If you want to limit the number of images, try to sort the images with time within One Hour. You will get what you want !!!

Comment: Post the code as answer and I will accept your answer if it works.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to post.  simply saying the things is easy, it's hard when it come to implement :)

Comment: Okey, I will wait for you answer.